# Redux-form doesn't read SelectField's value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, material-ui, redux-form

I have a very simple form with react and redux-form. What I wanna achieve is to get all the field values of my form and send them with jQuery ajax to my RESTful api.

Now my only problem is that apparently redux-form doesn't read SelectField's value. For example when I look at redux-devTools, except SelectFields, every other input is out there. I searched a lot and read the whole docs and I realized that SelectField's are a little bit tricky in redux-form but I can't seem to get it to work. How can I get SelectFields values with redux-form v5.3.1 ?

I'm using :

- Material-ui v0.15.4
- Redux-form v5.3.1
- React v15.3.0

#### Edit 1:

I tried different approaches:

**First**: Using `onChange` on `SelectField`

```
                        <SelectField
                            ref="customerGroup"
                            {...customerGroup}
                            fullWidth
                            floatingLabelText="customer group"
                            value={this.state.selectedCustomerGroup}
                            maxHeight={200}
                            onChange={(e,s,value)=>setState({selectedCustomerGroup: value}}
                        >
                            {groups}
                        </SelectField>
```

**Second**: using `setState` on `SelectField`'s children

```
                        for(let group of groupsArray){
        groups.push(<MenuItem className={style.menuItem} value={group.id} key={group.id} primaryText={group.name} onTouchTap={()=>this.setState({selectedCustomerGroup: group.id})}/>);
    }
                        <SelectField
                            ref="customerGroup"
                            {...customerGroup}
                            fullWidth
                            floatingLabelText="customer group"
                            value={this.state.selectedCustomerGroup}
                            maxHeight={200}
                            {groups}
                        </SelectField>
```

My constructor:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        selectedCustomerGroup: 1
    };
}
```

and here [image: this] you can see that there's everything BUT my `customerGroup` which is my `SelectField`

**Edit 16/27/8:**

Because of this exact problem I'm planing to ditch redux-form.

Comment: Would you share your code piece for select?

Comment: @Tugrul Here I added my codes and the redux state of my form

Answer (score 1):

I need to say that you don't need to hold values into local state. It's just a suggestion.

Second, check Redux-Form best practices. Inspect open source projects from github etc.  If custom components doesn't give you any advantages, stay cool and use the simplest one, maybe pure html tag.

Third, use fetch api instead of jquery xhr etc.

Be careful about setState and refs!

My answer is (as your coding pattern)

```
<SelectField
                        ref="customerGroup"
                        {...customerGroup}
                        fullWidth
                        floatingLabelText="customer group"
                        value={this.state.selectedCustomerGroup}
                        maxHeight={200}
                        onChange={(e,s,value)=>{customerGroup.onChange(e);setState({selectedCustomerGroup: value})}}
                    >
                        {groups}
                    </SelectField>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
const renderSelectField = props => (
  <SelectField
    floatingLabelText={props.label}
    errorText={props.touched && props.error}
    {...props}
    onChange={(event, index, value) => props.onChange(value)}>
  </SelectField>
)


<Field name="favoriteColor" component={renderSelectField} label="Favorite Color">
  <MenuItem value={'ff0000'} primaryText="Red"/>
  <MenuItem value={'00ff00'} primaryText="Green"/>
  <MenuItem value={'0000ff'} primaryText="Blue"/>
</Field>
```

Courtesy: [Latest redux-form docs](https://redux-form.com/6.0.0-rc.1/examples/material-ui/)